# Is there any way to write into logs if c# request class did not pass [Required]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

//Here is the sample code in my request class:

```
[Required]
public long myID { get; set; }
```

// I am planning to write something in log like this if ever the Required //value is not satisfied:

```
Response":{"Status":"1","Output":null}}}|
```

//   I wanted to add something like this to my controller:

```
if (RequiredAttribute.IsDefined) 
            {
                response.Status = "1";
                goto Finish;
            }
```

//Finish is the one that runs to write logs

Comment: it can achieve with middleware   Configure method in startup class

Comment: @JameelNazir do you know the syntax to read if [Required] value is satisfied or not?

Comment: So what have you setup in terms of logging in your app - are you using the provided ILogger ?

Comment: @auburg yes, I struggling with what syntax to catch it to write to logs, something like this  if (RequiredAttribute.IsDefined) 
            {
                response.Status = "1";
                goto Finish;
            }

Comment: Please can you post a complete example of your controller code

Comment: @auburg I updated the code, can you help with the correction of syntax (RequiredAttribute.IsDefine)?

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0 : if this a webapi controller then you don't have to do anything : anything that calls with an empty myID  property asp.net will automatically return a 400 result (which would be logged) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#automatic-http-400-responses

Comment: @auburg it is a web api controller. I included  if(!ModelState.IsValid){ //write to logs} yet it won't write anything, it just proceeded exiting ng endpoint

Comment: @Jinna see my amended comment

Comment: @auburg thank you for the links! it helped me. I just added error message and it writes to log  -> [Required(ErrorMessage = "message")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added Error Message and it automatically write to logs the error(400)

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "ID is required")]
public long ID { get; set; }
```